# I am having visualforce page which performs some action and then redirects me to the latest list view. It works in classic, but not in lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience, actionsupport

I am a new SF developer.
I am using below code to redirect the user once an action is perform to the previous list view.

```
nextPage = new ApexPages.action('{!list}').invoke();
return nextPage
```

It works perfectly fine in classic. However, in lightning it behaves really weird. Sometimes it redirects me to the correct view. Other times it resets the view.

For instance..
On the case object, the default list view selected is 'Recently viewed cases'. I select a different list view and from there I navigate to my VF page.
After performing the action, it redirects me back to 'Recently viewed cases' in the lightning version.
Sometimes, it brings me back to my selected view.